# Extract Only Specified Data in a string SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a review column in a table which has multiple strings formats like below,

Example strings:

```
Reviews_Column_Data [INPUT]
'05012:000000:  :0:00000000|00647:000000:  :0:00000000|00283:000000:  :0:00000000|'
'05012:000000:  :0:00000000|00025:000000:  :0:00000000|00647:000000:  :0:00000000|'
'05012:000000:  :0:00000000|02095:000000:  :0:00000000|00647:000000:  :0:00000000|'
'05012:000000:  :0:00000000|00647:000000:  :0:00000000|' 
'05081:023931:DF:9:20230111|00604:023931:XX:9:20230111|02470:023931:XX:9:20230111|00655:023931:XX:9:20230111|00464:023931:XX:9:20230111|02130:023931:XX:9:20230111|'
'05081:023931:DF:9:20230131|02229:023931:XX:9:20230131|02130:023931:XX:9:20230131|00692:023931:XX:9:20230131|02170:023931:XX:9:20230131|05084:000000:  :0:00000000|00647:000000:  :0:00000000|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             '
```

I need to extract the review in Application table in the below format...

```
Application_Review_Column_Data [OUTPUT]

'05012,00647,00283'
'05012,00025,00647'
'05012,02095,00647'
'05012,00647', 
'05081,00604,02470,00655,00464,02130' 
'05081,02229,02130,00692,02170,05084,00647'
```

Key Point to find the reviews is, starting point of the string and each end point of **symbol "|" and Immediate ":"**

I have tried with the below code, but it didn't work

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Temp_Tbl
 Create table #Temp_Tbl (Comments varchar(500));

 INSERT INTO #Temp_Tbl
 VALUES('05012:000000:  :0:00000000|00647:000000:  :0:00000000|00283:000000:  :0:00000000|'),
 ('05012:000000:  :0:00000000|00025:000000:  :0:00000000|00647:000000:  :0:00000000|'),
 ('05012:000000:  :0:00000000|02095:000000:  :0:00000000|00647:000000:  :0:00000000|'),
 ('05081:023931:DF:9:20230131|02229:023931:XX:9:20230131|02130:023931:XX:9:20230131|00692:023931:XX:9:20230131|02170:023931:XX:9:20230131|')
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Comments, ' ', ''), ':', ''), '000000000000000|', ',') FROM #Temp_Tbl 

But this is not working for the string format like "'05081:023931:DF:9:20230131|02229:023931:XX:9:20230131|02130:023931:XX:9:20230131|00692:023931:XX:9:20230131|02170:023931:XX:9:20230131|'"

Comment: [string_split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) on pipe `|` character, [charindex()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to find the `:`, [left()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to extract the required string. [string_agg()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to concatenate it back

Comment: STRING_SPLIT(Comments,'|') 
 STRING_SPLIT(Comments,':')...I could not able to concatenate with the string_agg() ...Could you please help me with an solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have commented, use `string_split` to split on `|`. Then charindex() and left() to extract the required string. Finally `string_agg()` to concatenate it back

```
 select Comments, 
        string_agg(case when p > 0 then left(c.value, p - 1) end, ',')
 from   #Temp_Tbl t
        cross apply string_split(Comments, '|') c
        cross apply (select p = charindex(':', c.value) ) p
group by Comments
```

Comment: The only problem that the SPLIT_STRING() function cannot guarantee a sequential order before SQL Server 2022 introduced such functionality.